# How to use aggregate function in SQL clause that is outside of what you are selecting?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, having

Sorry for the messy title.

I have a database containing different movie titles and each genre that each movie is a part of.
I would like to select movies under the genre of "short" that have a movie length that is greater than the average length of movies under all genres.

Genres are denoted as either 1 for yes or 0 for no.
This is my select statement so far:

```
SELECT MovieTitle, MovieLength
FROM MOVIES
WHERE GenreShort = 1
HAVING MovieLength > AVG(MovieLength)
```

How would I go about comparing movie length to the average of all movies and not just "short" genre movies?

Comment: The average must be calculated first, in a separate query (a "subquery"). Then the comparison will be in the `WHERE` clause; you can't have a `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY`. You are not grouping your short movies in any way; the fact that the average is an aggregate is a separate, unrelated issue.

Comment: Having a new column for each genre is an anti-pattern. You should have a genre table listing all genres, then a link table with a row for each genre that a movie has. Once done queries and tables don't need to change when adding genres, it will likely save space, can make it easier to make use of indexes, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use an analytic function to only `SELECT` from the table once:

```sql
SELECT MovieTitle,
       MovieLength
FROM   (
  SELECT MovieTitle,
         MovieLength,
         AVG(MovieLength) OVER () AS average_movielength
  FROM   MOVIES
  WHERE  GenreShort = 1
)
WHERE  movielength > average_movielength;
```

If you want to select from the table twice then:

```sql
SELECT MovieTitle,
       MovieLength 
FROM   MOVIES 
WHERE  GenreShort = 1 
AND    MovieLength > (SELECT AVG(MovieLength) FROM MOVIES);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1fb6b5316d23b29bfd4d0d9356bc6e3)*

Answer (score 0):

Use a **subquery** to get the average for all movies and then use that in your comparison, you also need a GROUP BY before using the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT MovieTitle, MovieLength 
FROM MOVIES 
WHERE GenreShort = 1 
GROUP BY MovieTitle, MovieLength 
HAVING MovieLength > (
                       SELECT AVG(MovieLength)
                       FROM MOVIES
                     );
```

OR Remove HAVING and GROUP BY

```
SELECT MovieTitle, MovieLength 
FROM MOVIES 
WHERE GenreShort = 1 AND MovieLength > (
                       SELECT AVG(MovieLength)
                       FROM MOVIES
                     );
```

Comment: Ah wonderful! I didn't know those existed. Thank you!

Comment: "HAVING" clause in a non-aggregate query? Seriously?

Comment: @mathguy Is your comment meant to be helpful in some way? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: I was under the impression that comparisons with aggregate clauses had to be in HAVING clauses.

Comment: You can move the `HAVING` filter into the `WHERE` clause and remove the `GROUP BY`.